# Why is the noun form of "permit" "permission"?

Tags: nouns, orthography, etymology

The noun form of *permit* is *permission* instead of *permition*. Why isn't it *permition*?

Comment: Because the Latin past participle, on which Latin *-Cio, -Cionis* constructions were built, of *mittere* was *missus -a, -um*.

Comment: @StoneyB That's an answer right there. Submit it so Popopo can accept and close this guy out.

Comment: @KenB As you wish.

Comment: see http://english.stackexchange.com/q/95195/3946

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Nominalizations of verbs with the suffix *-ion* are derived from Latin, whether by direct borrowing, or through an intermediary (usually French), or by analogy.

In Latin, the *-io, -ionis* suffix is appended to the stem of the past participle. For instance, the past participle of *portare*, "carry", is *portatus*, stem *portat-*, so the derived verbs *import*, *export*, *deport* are nominalized as *importa**tion***, *exporta**tion***, *deporta**tion***.

In the case of the verb *mittere*, "send", the past participle is *missus*, so the derived verbs *emit*, *commit*, *permit* are nominalized as *emi**ssion***, *commi**ssion***, *permi**ssion***.